# Group by not returning results in date order

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

In my project when a user views a video it will be inserted into a table which is used to store viewed movies details.

I am using the following query to get the movies viewed by the current user in order of latest records. If the user has viewed a video many times, it should return only the latest record among them.

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT vm.watched_on,vm.movie_id,cp.channel_id,
v.title, v.videothumbnail, v.views, v.likes, v.length, v.videoid,
cp.title as videotitle, cv.thumbnail,cv.views as cvviews,cv.likes as cvlikes, cv.id,cp.starttime,cp.endtime,vm.videotype
FROM viewedmovies as vm
LEFT JOIN video as v
ON (vm.movie_id=v.videoid AND vm.user_id=1 AND vm.videotype=1 and v.permission!=-1)
LEFT JOIN channel_videos as cv
ON (vm.movie_id=cv.id AND vm.user_id=1 AND (vm.videotype=0 or vm.videotype=2))
LEFT JOIN channel_programmes as cp
ON (vm.movie_id=cp.programme_source AND (vm.videotype=0 or vm.videotype=2) AND cp.status!=-1) 
where vm.user_id=1 GROUP BY vm.user_id, vm.movie_id, vm.videotype
ORDER BY vm.watched_on desc
LIMIT 6
```

Videos are stored in two tables: If the *videotype* in *viewedmovies* is 1 it will query from videos table and if the *videotype* is 0, it will query from *channel_programmes* and *channel_videos*. This query is returning results but not in order of date.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c382/1

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey jenZ see after a long time

Comment: i saw you after updating a question. after long time on stackoverflow?

Comment: send me a mail or chat request to my email id

Comment: Post your expected output too

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c382/55

```
SELECT vm.watched_on,vm.movie_id,cp.channel_id,
v.title, v.videothumbnail, v.views, v.likes, v.length, v.videoid,
cp.title as videotitle, cv.thumbnail,cv.views as cvviews,cv.likes as cvlikes, cv.id,cp.starttime,cp.endtime,vm.videotype
FROM
(
     SELECT x.*
     FROM
     (
         SELECT user_id, movie_id, watched_on, videotype
         FROM viewedmovies
         ORDER BY watched_on DESC
     ) as x
     GROUP BY x.user_id, x.movie_id
) as vm
LEFT JOIN video as v
    ON (vm.movie_id=v.videoid AND vm.user_id=1 AND vm.videotype=1 and v.permission!=-1)
LEFT JOIN channel_videos as cv
    ON (vm.movie_id=cv.id AND vm.user_id=1 AND (vm.videotype=0 or vm.videotype=2))
LEFT JOIN channel_programmes as cp
    ON (vm.movie_id=cp.programme_source AND (vm.videotype=0 or vm.videotype=2) AND cp.status!=-1) 
WHERE vm.user_id=1 
ORDER BY vm.watched_on desc
```

Comment: @Rachael..It is still not returning records in the order of date.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  Are you wanting the results ordered per movie or by the entire group?

Comment: It should order by group which contains the latest records for a particular video.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood.  I've updated the answer.  That should work as the base to get the rest of the information.

Comment: @Rachael..I want to query from two tables for video as I have done in given query.

Comment: I've updated the answer the add the two tables.  Hope that helps